# Overlap image texture on a material

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders, image

I'm trying to understand nodes, I have this complex material with PBS images textures combined  by color dodge mixer node with a gradient texture for paint it half white and half aqua green.

First I want know if this is the good way to do that.
[image]

Then I wanna add an overlay texture (made with photoshop and graphic tablet) to add some details:

[image]

So I've tried with mix shader:

[image]

On the viewport shading It's seems working (even if it's lighter):

[image]

On cycles' preview seems the material is letting pass light trough, in some areas, and the texture is almost invisible:

[image]

I've tried also by using one single principle BDSF by adding a mix node but the texture is already almost invisible (I've tried different type of mix without any success)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You're currently telling Blender that there's transparency behind your image, but after that it is mixed with a *Mix Shader* that is a 50/50% mix between your wall background and your image. In order to put your image over the wall you need to plug the *Alpha* output of your image into the *Factor* socket of the *Mix Shader*, not into the *Alpha* socket of the *Principled BSDF*, so basically, if I simplify, it should look like that:

[image]

Comment: I tried yesterday also this option after watching some tutorial but the resul was a weird effect with some fluo coolred patches, now I just switched the two BSDF on the Mix shader and it works fine!!! Thnx... I was supposing that the position of the two doesn't matter....